# Grails get list of available data sources

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Is there a way to get a list of available `dataSource`s in grails (or using hibernate methods)?

Let's say I have this in my config:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE"
}

dataSource_ALT {
   dbCreate = "update"
   url = "jdbc:h2:mem:altDb;MVCC=TRUE"
}
```

How can I know at runtime I have these data sources (and possibly switch them)?

I am using `grails 2.4.3` specifically.

Comment: Does this help? https://guides.grails.org/grails-dynamic-multiple-datasources/guide/index.html inject @Autowired
    HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore and access hibernateDatastore.connectionSources.getProperties().get("allConnectionSources")

Comment: I've also used grailsApplication.config.getProperty("dataSources.alt.url", String) to get access to current datasource configs.

Comment: @JasonHeithoff I get this error ERROR: No such property: connectionSources for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore

Comment: Try this import instead: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore

Comment: @JasonHeithoff That is the exact same class in my error.